# Opencart email new customer

Tags: php, email, opencart2.x

I want to disable email confirmation when new customer registers in my store, can someone help me to do it? I use version 2.3.1 opencart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable from admin. Go to admin > **System > Settings > Edit your store > Option Tab** > Account > then select option "**No**" for "New Account Alert Mail".

[image]